# IceFaces selectInputDate value changes after getting data

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I have an `ice:selectInputDate` but the value of the component is not the same as in the backing bean. I have to select two different dates to successfully update the variable value of the backing bean.

What am I missing?

What I want to do is to populate a table after getting some data from the DB with the date as a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post some code to get a better idea. Are you using a valueChangeListener and partialSubmit? If so, if you set the variable in the listener it would be the same in the bean as soon as you select the inputDate. 
You can populate the table from the listener
for example:

```
public void dateListener(ValueChangeEvent evt){

  yourDate = (Date) evt.getNewValue();
  //get your data for the table
}
```